# Java concurrency support using java.util.concurrent semantics

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to support modification (deactivate() function call) of the following data structure in a thread safe manner -

```
 private static Map<String, Set<Integer>> dbPartitionStatus = new HashMap<String, Set<DBPartitionId>>();

 public void deactivate(DBPartitionId partition) throws Exception {
    synchronized (dbPartitionStatus) {
        Set<DBPartitionId> partitions = dbPartitionStatus.get(serviceName);
        if (partitions == null) {
            partitions = new HashSet<DBPartitionId>();
        }
        partitions.add(partition);
        dbPartitionStatus.put(serviceName, partitions);
    }
}
```

If I were to replace the synchronization with ConcurrentHashMap & ConcurrentSkipListSet duo, there would be some race condition.

I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of achieving synchronization here (using java.util.concurrent)

Comment: "there would be some race condition" <-- which ones?

Comment: java.util.concurrent.locks.*?  If that's "cleaner" than synchronization, I will not speculate :)

Answer (score 0):

Should be no race conditions with the following implementation:

```
private final static ConcurrentMap <String, Set <DBPartitionId>> dbPartitionStatus = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap <String, Set <DBPartitionId>> ();

public void deactivate (DBPartitionId partition) {
    Set <DBPartitionId> partitions = dbPartitionStatus.get (serviceName);
    if (partitions == null)
    {
        partitions = new ConcurrentSkipListSet <DBPartitionId> ();
        Set <DBPartitionId> p = 
            dbPartitionStatus.putIfAbsent (serviceName, partitions);
        if (p != null) partitions = p;
    }
    partitions.add (partition);
}
```

Comment: well, we've to add partition to partitions set.

Answer (score -1):

I personally cannot see a issues with this sort of approach:

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentSkipListSet<DBPartitionId>> dbPartitionStatus = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public bool deactivate(DBPartitionId partition) throws Exception {
  ConcurrentSkipListSet<DBPartitionId> partitions = dbPartitionStatus.get(serviceName);
  if (partitions == null) {
    // Create a new set
    partitions = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<DBPartitionId>();
    // Attempt to add, if we add, ev will be null.
    ConcurrentSkipListSet<DBPartitionId> ev  = dbPartitionStatus.put(serviceName, partitions);
    // If non-null, someone else has added it, so now use it.
    if (ev != null)
      partitions = ev;
  }
  // will return true if added succesfully...
  return partitions.add(partition);
}
```

There is also the `putIfAbsent()` method in map which can do the get/put onthe map in an "atomic" operation, however it has the additional overhead in this case that you have to construct an empty set to pass in each time.

Comment: `put` return the `previous value` associated with key, or `null` if there was no mapping for key, so there will have `NullPointerException`. LINK:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#put

Comment: `partitions = dbPartitionStatus.put(serviceName, new ConcurrentSkipListSet<DBPartitionId>());` also has race condition while many threads replace `serviceName ` with `new ConcurrentSkipListSet<DBPartitionId>()`

Comment: @lichengwu, oops, I changed the code last minute without looking, it's dumb that it returns null for a new insert (it's been a few years since I've used it in anger.) Anyways, where is the race? Only on thread will succeed in inserting an entry, the other threads will see the new entry on their attempt to insert. Else what is the point of the concurrent map?

Comment: suppose two thread arrive `dbPartitionStatus.put(serviceName, partitions);` the two `partitions` are not same!! one `partitions` will replace another.

Comment: @lichengwu, yes, so, now work through it, *only one* can insert, which means the *other thread will receive the already inserted instance* as the return value, which then overrides the local instance in that thread, and the partition is inserted *into the same instance of the set in both threads* (same semantics apply with the set) That's not a race, that works as expected.